# zigbee control application with android on IMX6 board

Tags: android, zigbee

I am dealing with a project in that my IMX6 processor on which android is ported is used  to interface with TI CC2530 zigbee module. I want to control zigbee nodes using the application on android board.The module is communicated via uart with the board.What all things i should do for creating Zigbee app which can control the zigbee homeautomation device?

Answer (score 2):

Get TI's [Z-Stack Linux Gateway](http://www.ti.com/z-stack) software running on the IMX6.  From that webpage:

> Z-Stack Linux Gateway is TI's ZigBee Home Gateway solution for Linux
>   systems.
>
> Z-Stack Linux Gateway notables include:
>
> 1. Ease of ZigBee integration into the IP (Internet Protocol) world, with
>      simplified APIs over socket
> 2. ZigBee middleware, abstracting a variety
>      of Home and Building Automation use cases
>
>    - Lighting control
>    - Alarm and security
>    - Energy management
>    - Network management and Over-The-Air firmware upgrade
> 3. Fast prototyping on BeagleBone Black platform,
>      powered by TI’s leading Sitara AM335x Cortex-A8 processor
> 4. **Ability to run on most Linux or Android-based platforms**
> 5. Based on Z-Stack, ZigBee
>      Pro 2012 protocol stack with ZCP (Zigbee Compliant Platform)
>      certification and 802.15.4 MAC certification
> 6. Leveraging TI’s ZNP
>      (ZigBee Network Processor) firmware
>
>    - Based on Z-Stack and ZigBee PRO
>        2012 protocol stack with ZCP (ZigBee Compliant Platform) certification
>    - Available low-power devices: low cost SimpleLink™ ZigBee CC2530 and
>        high performance SimpleLink ZigBee CC2538
>    - Incorporated support for the
>        SimpleLink Range Extenders CC2591 and CC2590. These RF front ends
>        support +22dBm and +14dBm transmit power respectively and provide
>        improved receive sensitivity (3-dB typical Improved RX sensitivity on
>        CC253X devices).